# Need to pass class at runtime generics scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, reflection

I think header of question is not clear but I try to explain here.

Lets say I have class **A** which takes a generic type **T**

```
class A[T] {
    // Doing some thing with T
}
```

Now I am instantiating its object but in place of **T** I will pass a class at runtime like

```
Class.forName("com.somthing.SomeClass")
new A[com.somthing.SomeClass]() //but I don't have com.somthing.SomeClass at compile time
```

But how can I use above class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, there is not `T` at runtime. Type parameters "disappeas" during erasure and are replaced by `java.lang.Object`:

```
$ echo 'class A[T] { def f(t: T): T = t }' > test.scala 
$ scalac test.scala 
$ javap -c A.class 
Compiled from "test.scala"
public class A<T> {
  public T f(T);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: areturn

  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```